# Date formatting and including days

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a csv file which has column of dates (D/M/Y format) and I want to convert it to days column. I used following approach:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
        import pandas as pd
        from pandas import Series, DataFrame

        #f = pd.read_csv(".some_file.csv")
In [2]: f=pd.DataFrame([['1/1/2013', 400, 1000]['2/1/2013', 500, 3000]], columns=['date','flights','distance'])

        f['date']=pd.to_datetime(f['date'], format='%d/%m/%y',errors='ignore')

        f['day']=f['date'].dt.weekday_name
```

I was expecting the day column. It appeared for the first time and I used that table too. However after clearing kernel I am getting NaT in date and NaN in day. After that days never appeared.
Am I doing anything wrong? If yes, how did day appeared for the first time?

Thanks for reading. Any help will be appreciated.

PS CSV has more than 330K rows. I have to assign day for each date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have incorrectly specified the `datetime` format *and* hidden the error by setting `errors='ignore'`. You need `'%Y'` for the full year (see [Python's `strftime` directives](http://strftime.org/)):

```
f['date'] = pd.to_datetime(f['date'], format='%d/%m/%Y', errors='coerce')
```

`errors='coerce'` will give `NaN` for non-convertible dates. Or, to raise errors, just omit the `errors` parameter altogether.

For such problems, it's good practice to look at `f.dtypes` to see whether your type conversion has succeeded. For example, you *should* see:

```
print(f['date'].dtype)
# datetime64[ns]
```

You should *not* see:

```
print(f['date'].dtype)
# object
```